# cannot change properties of db-32.log

Tags: activemq-classic, jbossfuse, kahadb

I am getting below Error in Fuse log. In order to solve it I thought I will give permission to db-32.log file but it doesn't allow me to change permission of this file. Instead I get a warning

> "cannot change properties of db-32.log"

Please find below the error log

```
07:17:20,163 | INFO | AMQ-1-thread-1 | ActiveMQServiceFactory | 197 - 
io.fabric8.mq.mq-fabric - 1.2.0.redhat-621084 | Broker amq failed to start. 
Will try again in 10 seconds
07:17:20,163 | ERROR | AMQ-1-thread-1 | ActiveMQServiceFactory | 197 - 
io.fabric8.mq.mq-fabric - 1.2.0.redhat-621084 | Exception on start: 
/opt/install/jboss/jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-084/data/amq/kahadb/db-32.log 
(Permission denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/install/jboss/jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-
084/data/amq/kahadb/db-32.log (Permission denied)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_91]
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)[:1.8.0_91]
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)[:1.8.0_91]
```

Comment: Describe exactly how you tried to change the permissions and what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Do you restart the broker under a different user than was previously used to run the broker? 
Make sure the OS level user that runs the broker has full access to the configured KahaDB folder on the file system.

Comment: Yes i restarted from a different user which doent have permission. The problem got solved when i changed permission with sudo command. Thanks